# Closing all MDI child forms on exit?

Tags: c#, mdi, mdichild

How to force all MDI child forms and `MDI` parent form to close on exit or window close?

Answer (score 1):

On `exit()` use `Application.Exit();`

It will close all the open forms including MDI child and parent too.